# How to get a max value of each matrix row and save them in another list?

Tags: python, list, max

I have got the such matrix as:

```
matrix = [ [0,0,2],[1,0,1],[2,1,0] ]
```

And I would like to get a list like:

```
[2,1,2]
```

the compare is column to each column, so matrix[0][0] compared with matrix[1][0] and matrix[2][0], thanks

another example like :

```
[[0,0,2],[1,0,1],[2,1,0],[2,1,3]]
```

And I would like to get a list like:

```
[2,1,3]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are happy to use a 3rd party library, `numpy` provides one way.

This assumes your list elements have the same length.

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[0,0,2],[1,0,1],[2,1,0],[2,1,3]])

res = A.max(axis=0)

# array([2, 1, 3])
```

Answer (score 4):

An alternative to List Comprehension, using `map` :

```
>>> list(map(max, l))
```

#driver values :

```
IN : l = [ [0,0,2],[1,0,1],[2,1,0] ]
OUT : [2, 1, 2]
```

**EDIT :** The above finds max for each inner-list. The same for the desired behaviour by the OP (column-wise) :

```
>>> list(map(max, zip(*l)))
```

#driver values :

```
IN : l = [[0,0,2],[1,0,1],[2,1,0],[2,1,3]]
OUT : [2, 1, 3]
```

Comment: perfect one ...+1 :)

Comment: Actually list comprehension is usually faster than `map` (given of course you perform a `list(..)` on the result).

Comment: the compare is column to each column, so matrix[0][0] compared with matrix[1][0] and matrix[2][0], thanks

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem : thanks. Had overlooked that for some reason. Have changed the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
lst = [ [0,0,2],[1,0,1],[2,1,0] ]

print [max(i) for i in lst]
```

Answer (score 0):

Combination of list comprehension, zip and reduction should also deliver required result:

```
matrix = [[0,0,2],[1,0,1],[2,1,0],[2,1,3]]

max_cols = [max(list(i)) for i in zip(*matrix)]
```

max_cols has max values of matrix columns - [2, 1, 3]

Answer (score -1):

As others have said you can use

```
>>> [max(i) for i in a]
[2, 1, 2]
```

But there is also this for the opposite of what you want

```
>>> [min(i) for i in a]
[0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: the compare is column to each column, so matrix[0][0] compared with matrix[1][0] and matrix[2][0], thanks